# Make time on bottom right disappear in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop-customization

I'm bored watching the time in Windows.

[image]

I am currently using Windows 8.1
Do you know how can I make the time to disappear?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So now, offices have to remove clocks to get people to be productive... :O

Comment: They can just make the clocks invisible to them..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **[Turn system icons on or off](http://www.howtogeek.com/172466/10-ways-you-can-customize-your-windows-taskbar/)** setting in the **Notification Area Icons** control panel applet to turn it off.

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter this:

```
control /name Microsoft.NotificationAreaIcons
```

Click on `Turn system icons on or off` and turn off Clock.

Windows 10 users can right click on the clock, select `Properties` and click on `Turn system icons on or off` (under Quick Actions) and turn off the Clock.